# Where is this redirect being set?

Tags: iis, redirect, coldfusion, web

I am trying to figure out where some redirects are being set for a web site I'm managing. It is an IIS server and the application is mainly in cold fusion. I have found with certainty that the IIS settings do not specify any redirects. No cold fusion settings that I've found allow redirects from the server side. There are no '< cflocation >' or header changes in the cold fusion files that would cause this redirect. Finally, there are no redirects in any of the .htaccess files. What other possible causes/locations could there be for a 301 redirect being set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Redirects can also be done with cfheader:

```
<cfheader statuscode="301" statustext="Moved permanently" />
<cfheader name="location" value="http://www.mysite.com/new-location-for-content/" />
```

Or there can be a Javascript redirect as well, something like:

```
document.location='http://www.mysite.com/new-location-for-content/';
```

Or there may be a bit of ASP, etc., etc.

More examples here http://www.somacon.com/p145.php